# INT values when importing CSV data from Funnel to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a rather unexpected problem with BigQuery

**When importing CSV data from Funnel to BigQuery**. I see that **BigQuery changes the values of my INT** columns during the load process.

I use Funnel to export data to BigQuery, and **Funnel correctly sends data in CSV format**. However, after the data is loaded into BigQuery, I notice **changes in the values of my INT columns**.

I have done extensive checks and I am convinced that the problem **is not on Funnel's side**, as the CSV data sent by Funnel is correct. INT values are correctly formatted and show no issues when exported from Funnel.

However, when importing into BigQuery, the values of the INT columns are changed.
I don't see this problem with other data types like STRING or DATE, which suggests the problem is specific to INT columns.

I wanted to know if anyone could know why I have this error and why BigQuery changes the values of my INT columns when importing CSV data from Funnel.

Thanks in advance

CSV sent from then Funnel :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au3TD.png)

Data received by BigQuery :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbBHv.png)